# How to reference another table in the Power BI query editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Is it possible to reference another table using M in Power BI?

I have a list of files in `TableA` and want to compare the data with a list in `TableB`.

I have done this in DAX by using related and was wondering does M have a similar function?

```
= SEARCH(related(keywords[keyword]),main[text],1,0)
```

Comment: You can reference another table just by using its name. Can you explain a bit more how you want to compare the lists? What is your end goal?

Comment: I have a table that contains descriptions of faults in products along with part number and other details. I have another table with a list of keywords like "burned", "cut", "dangerous", "wrong" etc. Each one of these has a value rating in another column. I need to search the main file to see if it contains one of the keywords and then attach a severity rating based on the keyword from the second table.  Thanks for your interest in the problem Alexis

Comment: Can you post a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with example input and desired output? Your comment helps, but an actual example would be much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled to find this information too.

This is a snippet from a Power Query 'Advanced Editor' where I'm reading a minimum date from another table into a variable.

```
let
    Source = #date(2015, 1, 1),
    MinDate = List.Min(TableName[Date]),
...
```

[Power Query List functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/list-functions)

Hopefully `List` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks I will try the list function out and let you know how it worked for me